# Fastest selector method in jquery and CSS - ID or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

**What is fastest in jquery/javascript?**

```
$('#myID .myClass')
```

or

```
$('.myClass')
```

**What is best to use in CSS?**

```
#myID .myClass{}
```

or

```
.myClass{}
```

**I see now that I should have explained better. Sorry!**

Ofceauce ID is a faster selector in both CSS and JavaScript. But some times you need to use class since there are multiple selectors.

Say forexample that I have i BIG html document. In the middle of the page I have:

```
<div id="myID">

<a class="myClass">link1</a>

<a class="myClass">link1</a>

<a class="myClass">link1</a>

</div>
```

If I want to target all "myClass". Would it then be better to target the ID before targeting the classes? (then I wouldn't have to do domtravel of the entire HTML document) Eg.:

Would this:

$('#myID').find('.myClass')

Be faster than:

$('.myClass')

Comment: I'm sorry but there should be only one element with a specific ID so the first could just be `$('#myID')` or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Different browsers have different DOM selection methods that are used, so there isn't a single correct answer. In older browsers, doing `$('#myID').find('.myClass')` is likely the fastest. In new browsers, I have a feeling that you won't see much difference unless you have a horribly large and complex page.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Actually I have a "horribly LARGE and complex page". Thats what got me into asking the question, but I only care about modern browsers.

Comment: Depending on your definition of "modern", modern browsers are going to use the native `querySelectorAll` method, which is generally very fast. But be careful. Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) adds non-standard selectors which `querySelectorAll` can't tolerate. So if you use one of those, control is given to its own JavaScript based engine, which is much slower. I think that either way, `$('#myID').find('.myClass')` will be very fast.

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100018/selector-for-best-performance-in-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My [testing](http://jsperf.com/testing-scoping-a-jqueru-selector-within-an-id) on *modern* browsers suggests that you should go with either,

```
$('#id').find('.class') // or
$('.class')
```

but *not*,

```
$('#id .class')
```

Reason being that all modern browsers implement `getElementsByClassName` resulting in almost-constant time lookups by class name (assuming a hash implementation). Which browsers are modern is another subjective question.

Comment: Cool test you got there! Maybe I should start using only class. :)

Comment: are you suggesting that in jQuery for selecting elements which are descendents we should always use `.find()` and never the space selector combinator of CSS3?

Answer (score 3):

They're roughly the same in most modern browsers since class-names are hashed internally.  The difference is that older browsers don't have a `.getElementsByClassName` or equivalent method, so `.myClass` is parsed internally to jQuery and EVERY element in the dom is walked and checked for the classname (or it uses XPath when possible).

Always try to use `#myID .myClass` when possible as it allows jQuery to jump directly to `#myID` and traverse from there when necessary.

Comment: So what happens to `.myClass` elements that exist outside of `#myID`?

Comment: The OP posted different selectors, so of course there are different use-cases and they will each generate different results.  I was pointing out that selecting `.myClass` is, in modern browsers, no slower than selecting `#myID .myClass`.  If, for instance, the only instances of `.myClass` are inside `#myID`, selecting `.myClass` directly will actually be faster in many browsers.  The difference is that in older browsers, selecting `.myClass` will be literally thousands of times slower, so `#myID .myClass` is always preferred.

Comment: @BoltClock wouldn't you handle your case with a simple $('.myClass'), sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.  Or when you say "So what happens to `.myClass`..." do you mean, how is the search handled/how is performance?  And I would guess that in either case (older browsers, vs. newer ones) since you're asking about `.myClass` alone... it would still have to traverse the tree starting with the root −► @zyklus: even if modern browsers do have a `.getElementsByClassName()` method - how is this method implemented differently so that @BoltClock's scenario would be different?

Comment: @Flak DiNenno: At the time I'd posted my comment there was no context in the question, so it was quite simply meaningless to compare both selectors for performance as they meant completely different things - one matches every `.myClass` and the other matches only the ones within the ID. Since the question was edited to give context my comment is obsolete.

Comment: @BoltClock ahhh... make sense now.  thx for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just think logically about this for a second, and pretend that you didn't know anything about how a browser is built internally or how it accesses the DOM, but you assume that whatever it does is logical.

Therefore, doesn't it stand to reason that out of two selectors, the narrowest one would find you results faster?

You have two selectors, which translate to rough english as

1. Any element of the class `myClass` that is a child of the element with ID of `myID`
2. Any element of the class `myClass`

As for "What is best to use in CSS", this is completely subjective as it depends if you are intending to target *all* instances of `.myClass` or just those that are children of `#myID`.

Comment: It cannot even be subjective, it just has no logic to deciding which one is "better" as both selectors don't pick the same set of elements in the first place. Oh and yeah have my upvote, please, for doing so.

Comment: Well that is what I mean by "subjective" - it's up for individual judgment based on the circumstances

Comment: That's actually not true.  All browsers with an internal `.getElementsByClassName` method will have nearly identical performance to selecting on an ID based on the fact that the class-names are hashed.

Comment: @cwolves, I am not making a point about actual modern browser implementations as of today, but more about using logical reasoning to deduce which approach would be faster. Even if the hash-based method for class names is "nearly identical", it cannot be faster than looking up a single ID - it can only match it.

Comment: @matt b -- actually `.myClass` is faster than `#myID .myClass` in some cases such as when the only instances of `.myClass` are inside of `#myID` and you're using a modern browser.  But I get the point of your post :)

Comment: I read somewhere that using class makes the browser travel through the whole document, while using ID makes the browser stop traveling when it finds the ID-selector. In my case it’s is not preferable to do full domtravel since I have a huge HTML file.I believe I also read that domtravel starts from bottom to top.
In CSS I believe I have read that using “#myID .myClass{}” makes the browser first look for all .myClass and then “exclude” all .myClass that are outside #myID. There are no .myClass outside #myID.
Very sorry for being unclear in my question!

Comment: Downvote because a narrower selector may require more computation to evaluate so the intuition is wrong, and since the practical result is wrong (see other answers).

Comment: @zyklus why is that?  aren't these instance `$('#myID .myClass')`, i.e. the nested ones, hashed just the same as these `$('.myClass')`, the non-nested ones?

Answer (score 2):

Good question actually.

Say you have parsed DOM of N elements of max depth of D and CSS of S number of rules. Then the task of finding styles for all elements has computational complexity of roughly `O(N*D*S)`.

Obviously not all of CSS selectors has the same computation complexity.

For example `li.item` selector and `li[class ~= "item"]` require exactly the same CPU resources as they are equivalents. `li[class = "item"]` can be computed faster as it does not require scan of white spaces.

#1 selector here:

```
#myID .myClass{} /* #1 */
.myClass{} /* #2 */
```

require more CPU resources as you need to do exactly the same amount of work as in case #2 plus you will need to scan parent/child chain (of max D elements) to find the element with "myID".

That is all about pure CSS selectors.

In jQuery & friends situation can be a bit different. Theoretically jQuery engine can use `document.getElementById()` to minimize the lookup set (so reduce the N number) but that will not match CSS behavior. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dnsUF/ . Here jQuery reports one element with `#foo` but there two such elements in fact.

Resume:

- In CSS case #2 is faster
- In jQuery case #1 can be faster (but technically may not be correct in CSS sense).

Here is my article about CSS selector complexity:
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2008/07/csss-and-computational-complexity-of-selectors/
And this one of how to improve it by using style sets:
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2010/09/style-sets-in-h-smile-core/

Comment: Just to clarify: What you are saying is that #1 is faster in CSS, but requires more CPU resources of the computer?

Comment: +1; good answer, but your complexity analysis looks iffy: you can almost certainly make a smart datastructure to look up the appropriate style rules more quickly than by linear scan; and similarly it's quite likely that you don't need to scan up the entire tree depth (intermediate results might be cached and shared between node lookups).  And then of course the expected time would be lower still since pathological selectors that require complete parent scanning are probably rare.  Similarly, I expect class-name whitespace splitting is cached, and does not happen during selector evaluation.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: CSS selectors work in different environment as jQuery selectors. For HTML/CSS you are given N DOM elements and S rules. For any given DOM element you have to scan all S selectors in specificity order to check if any of them will match. And if "yes" the style will be combined with what you have to the moment. You can do some optimizations here but not that many - in any case it is `O(N*S*D)` on initial DOM state.

Comment: I see the naive implementation you're inferring here - and *if* that's how you implement style matching, sure, you need O(N*D*S).  But it's not clear you actually need to use that algorithm.  You *can* preprocess the style rules to make matching more efficient, for instance by making indexes for things like class names and element names.  And if you encounter two rules start with the same lookup key... merge the rules in your preprocessing and use a TRIE like structure.  It's not at all clear that you need to scan style rules *at all* during matching; you may well be able to use a lookup-tree.

Answer (score 1):

IDs will always be the fastest way to access an element, since they are unique.

Comment: Quite optimistic I would say. What if they are not unique? All browsers support multiple elements having the same ID. Here is test for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Fu4At/

Comment: @c-smile: Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I've seen it happen in action :) Quite a head bang

Comment: @BoltClock: uniqueness of IDs is a recommendation for authors.

Comment: @c-smile IDs are unique by definition. Reusing an ID is not only bad practice, it's also impractical as the browser would always select the first element with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, id is one of the fastest method to access element. Check it out this test http://mootools.net/slickspeed/.

Answer (score 1):

`#myID .myClass` is definitely a better way to access the element assuming you have many elements to which the `.myClass` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Update - 2015 - Check yourself here
[https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2](https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2/)

**TL;DR;**

*Using ID $("#foo")  is almost 4x faster than CSS $(".bar") on my chrome 41 on linux 64bits*