# HTML/JS good practices: Is it good to add too many ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an HTML page where I would like to add elements to a specific list, like so:

```
<div id="list-of-divs">
<div id="name-specific-id">
// content
</div>

<div id="another-id">
//content
</div>
.
.
.
<div id="yet-another-id">
</div>
```

Now I want to add new `div`s to that list, say with the following:

```
<div id="new-option-panel">
<input id="first-textbox-id" type="text">
<input id="second-textbox-id" type=text">
<button>Add new option</button>
```

Of course, the addition is done with jQuery code.

My question is: is it a good practice to add *many* such `id`s in HTML code and depend on them in my jQuery code, or is it a bad practice for both HTML and jQuery, and I should find other ways in my jQuery code (depending on DOM traversing, for example)?

Just for example of what I mean: will adding to many `id`s slow Javascript execution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Id's are faster to query but very tedious to maintain, so I'd take the "performance hit" and make my code more obvious by using classes and id's only when necessary. In your example I would probably keep the id on the div but the input elements don't need one, a simple class will do for both jQuery and CSS or even no class at all.

Comment: Also, selectors like `#important-element .specific-subelement` tend to give more obvious context and are generally more readable than just `#specific-subelement`.

Comment: + 1 I would also say that ids are faster. I also want to add that in some cases you can't use this without the id - if every item is a record in a database that should be persiststed/upated for example. And the id on the the input can be important if every field has a label, that is not wrapped around it.

Comment: @lanzz This answer and the benchmark in the provided link could be interesting: [Fastest selector method in jquery and CSS - ID or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036723/1456376)

Comment: @insertusernamehere: That's interesting but expected I guess. `getElementsByClassName` is faster than `querySelectorAll` that I suppose it's what the full string `#id .class` uses...

Comment: That's true - I only wanted to add it in addition or let's say as a note/hint.

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with JSPerf tho because generic tests are usually very unreliable but good tests can provide useful hints to improve your code's performance. When implementing native browser features I just choose the most convenient, in this case `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Id selectors followed by Tag selectors are the best ones because they map directly to the native `.getElementById()` and `.getElementByTag()` methods

I would suggest that you always descend from the closest parent Id when you traverse the DOM. As in most languages there is always a readability/performance tradeoff that you will have to consider for your particular application.

Check out these performance guidelines for further insights

http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/