# For performance, should I chain selector calls or let jQuery do the work?

Tags: jquery

In terms of browser performance, should I chain selector calls? Does jQuery do a full document search regardless?

For example the difference between `$('.my_thing') and $('#outer_div .my_thing')`

Comment: jQuery typically uses `document.querySelectorAll()`, so the browser is doing the optimization. The only exceptions are when the selector is `".someclass"` or `"#someelement"` or `"thetagname"`. I would expect just the class to be faster because it gets sent to `document.getElementsByClassName()`, however i haven't tested this because it's a premature optimization and it's usually better to use whatever makes more sense rather than what's faster in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read this article on 24ways: [Your jQuery: Now With 67% Less Suck.](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/) especially the *Selector optimization* part.

As you will see in modern browsers the class selectors are really fast, but not in < IE8.

I recommend not to use `$('#outer_div .my_thing')`, much better `$('#outer_div').find('.my_thing')`.

Comment: @Scottie The world is small or S.O. is big :) Nice to see you here!

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the selector.

In your case, assuming you don't have `.my_thing` elements outside of `#outer_div`, both selectors will be very fast as they'll use the underlying `getElementsByTagName`.

You're comparing two very fast selectors here, so the difference doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Common sense says the first example, because the second example requires the extra step of finding the first element and then traversing its DOM branch until it finds the second element.

Imagine you are searching the DOM for the first element, you could actually *pass* the second element (that you are looking for) because the loop's terminal condition is finding the first element.

As with most performance tweaks, the improvements will be browser-dependent.

Related:
[Fastest selector method in jquery and CSS - ID or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035348/fastest-selector-method-in-jquery-and-css-id-or-not#)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some useful articles on the topic:

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html
http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-performance-tips-cheat-sheet/
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/

To sum up, with introduction of Sizzle, the mentioned queries should give roughly the same performance numbers. If you use older versions, first approach should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

**'#id'** selector is the fastest and **find** is the browser native method

```
$('#outer_div').find('.my_thing'); 
// or shorthand 
$('.my_thing', '#outer_div');
```